# Use isEqualByComparingTo in Predicate

Tags: comparison, predicate, matcher, assertj

normal use of nice assertj-matchers like `isEqualByComparingTo`:

```
BigDecimal number = ...
assertThat(number).isEqualByComparingTo(BigDecimal.valueOf(...));
```

however I have a list of BigDecimals and want to check each element in the list for equality by using assertj's matchers like `isEqualByComparingTo`:

```
List<BigDecimal> numbers = ...
assertThat(numbers).allMatch( ???.isEqualByComparingTo(BigDecimal.valueOf(...) )
```

instead i have to use the tedious low-level comparisons:

```
List<BigDecimal> numbers = ...
assertThat(numbers).allMatch( number -> number.compareTo(...) == 0 )
```

is it somehow possible, to use the nice matchers inside a predicate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [`usingElementComparator`](http://joel-costigliola.github.io/assertj/assertj-core-features-highlight.html#custom-comparison-strategy) with [`BigDecimalComparator`](http://joel-costigliola.github.io/assertj/core-8/api/org/assertj/core/util/BigDecimalComparator.html) (or write your own BigDecimalComparator).

Example:

```
List<BigDecimal> numbers = list(new BigDecimal("1.00"), new BigDecimal("2.00"));

assertThat(numbers).usingElementComparator(new BigDecimalComparator())
                   .contains(new BigDecimal("1.0"), new BigDecimal("2"));
```